# LaTeX engine crashes if MiKTeX installed after RStudio

Tags: windows, latex, rstudio, pandoc, pdflatex

Note: this request has also been made on the [RStudio Support](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/204460047-pdflatex-exe-crashing-if-MikTex-is-installed-after-RStudio?locale=en-us) site

On two separate Windows machines (both running Windows 7 Enterprise) I've found that if  MiKTeX is installed before RStudio I can create pdf output without problem.  But, if the installation order is reversed, the LaTeX engine crashes (this happens pdflatex.exe, lulatex.exe, and xelatex.exe).

What's worse, if RStudio is uninstalled and then re-installed to fix the order, the problem remains.

The specific error message I get is:

```
pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF from TeX source
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" stuff.utf8.md
--to latex 
--from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash-implicit_figures 
--output stuff.pdf
--template "I:\R-Library\rmarkdown\rmd\latex\default.tex" 
--highlight-style tango 
--latex-engine pdflatex 
--variable "geometry:margin=1in"' 
had status 43 
Execution halted
```

I've validated that my path variable for the MiKTeX binary file is correct and running `Sys.which("pdflatex.exe")` returns the correct path as well.

Thanks in advance for any help fixing this issue.